# Postgresql 8.4 Like Concat

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, concatenation, postgresql-8.4

my query in postgresql 9.3 is:

```
SELECT *
    FROM route
    WHERE 'my/uri/address' LIKE CONCAT(c_uri, '%')
```

But in postgresql 8.4 this code not working.

How can i resolve, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "*not working*" mean? Do you get an error? If yes which one. Also: both 9.3 and 8.4 are no longer supported. Especially 8.4 is really, really outdated. You should plan an upgrade for both environments now

Comment: I cant upgrade - this is shared hosting.
Query not return result. Is v 8.4 support LIKE CONCAT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL version 8.4 to String concatenation use `||` operation.

Example:`'Post' || 'greSQL'`

Result is: `PostgreSQL`

Comment: Thanks! This help me!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `WS_CONCAT` function but it is not defined in 8.4. You can declare it as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION concat_ws(
   separator text,
   VARIADIC names_array text[]
)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN array_to_string(array_remove(names_array, NULL), ' ');
END;
$$;
```

This definition works exactly as in 9.x and above: pass the separator text first and then an arbitrary amount of texts to concat. `NULL` values get filtered out.

Example:

```
SELECT WS_CONCAT(' ', 'Ford', 'Focus', NULL /* Missing body-style */, '1.8 L')
```

Result: `Ford Focus 1.8 L`